# cuda kernel gives incorrect results by grid size increase

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I am testing a simple CUDA algorithm for timing and I came across a case that when I increase the grid size of the kernel it gives incorrect results:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* we need these includes for CUDA's random number stuff */
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

#define MAX 10

#ifdef GRID
    #define REPEAT GRID
#else 
    #define REPEAT 65535  
#endif  

#ifdef VECSIZE
    #define SIZE VECSIZE 
#else 
    #define SIZE 1024  
#endif 


__global__ void random(int *result) {

    curandState_t state;
    curand_init(100, 0, threadIdx.x, &state);
    result[threadIdx.x] = curand(&state) % MAX;
    //printf("th %d random %d\n", threadIdx.x, *result);
}

__global__ void myadd(const int *in, int *sum) {
    sum[blockIdx.x] = 0;
    //printf("thread %d value %d\n",threadIdx.x,  in[threadIdx.x]);
    atomicAdd_block(&sum[blockIdx.x], in[threadIdx.x]);
    //atomicAdd(sum, in[threadIdx.x]);
}

int main() {
    int check = 0;
    /* allocate an int on the GPU */
    int *x = new int[SIZE];
    int *sum = new int[REPEAT];
    int *d_x, *d_sum;
    cudaMalloc(&d_x, sizeof(int) * SIZE);
    cudaMalloc(&d_sum, sizeof(int) * REPEAT);

    /* invoke the GPU to initialize all of the random states */
    random<<<1, SIZE>>>(d_x);

    myadd<<<REPEAT, SIZE>>>(d_x, d_sum);  
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        /* copy the random number back */
    cudaMemcpy(x, d_x, sizeof(int) * SIZE, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(sum, d_sum, sizeof(int)* REPEAT, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        check += x[i];
        //printf("Random[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]);
    }

    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError(); // Get error code

    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("CUDA Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < REPEAT; ++i) {
        printf("i %d check %d  sum[i] %d\n", i, check, sum[i]);
        assert(check == sum[i]);        
    }
        /* free the memory we allocated */
    cudaFree(d_x);
    cudaFree(d_sum);
    delete[] x;
    delete[] sum;

    return 0;
}
```

My card is V100 with compute capability of 7.0. As you can see I can compile the above code with different grid and vector sizes with `nvcc test.cu -arch=sm_70 -O3 -g -G -DGRID=1024 -DVECSIZE=512`, for small vector and grid sizes everything looks good but when I increase the grid size to max (65535) sometimes the computed sum value is incorrect. For example:

```
.
.
.
i 511 check 2331  sum[i] 2331
i 512 check 2331  sum[i] 2331
i 513 check 2331  sum[i] 2188
a.out: test.cu:87: int main(): Assertion `check == sum[i]' failed.
```

Comment: This is not C. Please don't spam tags.

Comment: CUDA has different APIs, like python and C, and this CUDA code is using C API

Comment: @user2348209 But this code is C++. Isn't there a CUDA C++ API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a race condition in kernel `myadd`. The sum must only be set to 0 once. And it should not be set to 0 after some other threads added their value to it.

```
__global__ void myadd(const int *in, int *sum) {
    if(threadIdx.x == 0){
        sum[blockIdx.x] = 0;
    }
    __syncthreads(); // all threads wait until sum is initialized with 0

    atomicAdd_block(&sum[blockIdx.x], in[threadIdx.x]);
}
```

If you want to time your code properly, you should remove the `-G` compiler flag.

Comment: thank you, you are right. Do I need this initialization at all? What gonna happen for a shared memory array without initialization? Is CUDA smart enough to initialize it to zero?

Comment: no CUDA does not initialize shared memory to zero.  and the type of memory you are using here is not shared memory but global memory.  CUDA also does not initialize global memory to zero.

Comment: thank you, I know here is not a shared memory, I just asked in general that if I can replace it.